# JQuery bxslider wrong calculation after scale container for horizontal mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

Hi I have a `bxslider` which is in a transformed/scaled container. How can I correct the calculation of the slide position. It seems like a normal reload doesn't affect the calculation when its container is scaled.

**//EDIT:** I found out that this problem effects not the `fade` mode of the bxslider, so this could be a workaround...

**How can the `horizontal` mode of the bxslider be fix, when the whole container got scaled down?**

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/wittich/umgwrh3b/

[image: jsfiddle bxslider example for wrong calculation]

---

***HTML***

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/trees.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p><a href="" id="reload-slider">Click to reload slider</a></p>
```

---

***JS***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var sliders = [];
    jQuery('.bxslider').each(function(i,item){
        var slider = $(this);
        slider.bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            mode: 'horizontal'
        });
        sliders[i] = slider;
    });

    $('.container').css('transform', 'scale(0.8)');

    $(sliders).each(function(){
        this.reloadSlider();
    });

    $('#reload-slider').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(sliders).each(function(){
            this.reloadSlider();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the `fade` mode as there is no necessity to calculate a movement of the elements...